# Save images to SFTP server using java

Tags: java, sftp, image-uploading

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
String SFTPHOST = "10.20.30.40";
int    SFTPPORT = 22;
String SFTPUSER = "username";
String SFTPPASS = "password";
String SFTPWORKINGDIR = "/export/home/kodehelp/";

Session     session     = null;
Channel     channel     = null;
ChannelSftp channelSftp = null;

try{
            JSch jsch = new JSch();
            session = jsch.getSession(SFTPUSER,SFTPHOST,SFTPPORT);
            session.setPassword(SFTPPASS);
            java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
            config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            session.setConfig(config);
            session.connect();
            channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
            channel.connect();
            channelSftp = (ChannelSftp)channel;
            channelSftp.cd(SFTPWORKINGDIR);
            URL url = new URL("https://65.media.tumblr.com/839a07990f2b1ffa32065513c6224493/tumblr_oe6t3aYpHc1qfilt7o1_500.jpg");
            BufferedImage image = null;
            image = ImageIO.read(url);

            **File f = new File(FILETOTRANSFER);
            channelSftp.put(new FileInputStream(f), f.getName());**
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I don't know, how to store image to SFTP server. I am confused about what to write instead of this two line

```
File f = new File(FILETOTRANSFER);

channelSftp.put(new FileInputStream(f), f.getName());
```

I am using JSCH library to connect with SFTP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're loading the image into a `BufferedImage`, but that's not a representation you can directly write to an SFTP server.

It's much easier to directly open an InputStream on the URL and save that to the SFTP server. (Using `url.openStream()`)

You then need to come up with a suitable file name - here I take the last part of the URL after the last slash, which has the same effect as what you did in your code.

```
URL url = new URL(
        "https://65.media.tumblr.com/839a07990f2b1ffa32065513c6224493/tumblr_oe6t3aYpHc1qfilt7o1_500.jpg");
String path = url.getPath();
channelSftp.put(url.openStream(),path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/')+1));
```

Comment: Last line channelSftp.put(url.openStream(),path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/'))); 
give error "Permission Denied". But when I changed the path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/')) to "1.jpg" its work great. 
Thank you for helping.

Comment: I understood that why path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/')) is not working. Because it gives substring that start from "/". And image (or file) name never start from "/".

Comment: @ParthPatel I see. You can add `+1` to the return value of `lastIndexOf`. I updated the answer.

Comment: Yes, I did same thing. I added `+1` to return value of `lastIndexOf`.